# Group NSDictionary by dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary and i want to group it creating an array of objects by date

Example of the main NSDictionary:

```
({

        date = "2014-04-27";
        group = "yellow.png";
        length = 180;

    },
        {

        date = "2014-04-28";
        group = "blue.png";
        length = 180;

    },
        {

        date = "2014-04-27";
        group = "blue.png";
        length = 120;

    })
```

I want to group something similar as:

```
2014-04-27 = (
{ 

            date = "2014-04-27";
            group = "yellow.png";
            length = 180;

        },
            {

            date = "2014-04-27";
            group = "blue.png";
            length = 180;

        })


  2014-04-28 = ( {

            date = "2014-04-28";
            group = "blue.png";
            length = 120;

        })
```

Could someone help me? i have tried many FOR but i cant get it

Comment: It must be noted that your first listing omits the rather critical containing array.  Your second example apparently assumes the the outer object will become a dictionary containing arrays.  You need to better understand your object nesting, I suspect.

Comment: (To get started on your question, first sort your array in the first case by date.  There is no "built-in" function to do this, you must use one of the NS(Mutable)Array `sortUsing` operations with the appropriate predicate structure.  There are easily a dozen recent examples of this exact scenario on SO, so do some searching before you ask how to do that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears as though your original data structure is an array of dictionaries. Was your question phrased incorrectly? I see each individual dictionary but they are not keyed on anything in the top level data structure.

Assuming that is the case (you have an array called `originalArray`

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in originalArray)
{
    NSString *dateString = dictionary[@"date"];
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithSameDate = dictionaryByDate[dateString];
    if(! arrayWithSameDate)
    {
        arrayWithSameDate = [NSMutableArray new];
        dictionaryByDate[dateString] = arrayWithSameDate;
    }
    [arrayWithSameDate addObject: dictionary];
}
```

By the end of this, `dictionaryByDate` will be a dictionary (keyed on date) of arrays (all objects in a given array will be dictionaries with the same date).